# Can you instantiate and initialize a SqlDataRecord in one statement?

Tags: c#

In C#, is there a way to instantiate and initialize a SqlDataRecord in one statement?

Instead of doing this in two statements:

```
var record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("n", SqlDbType.BigInt));
record.SetInt64(0, someLongVal);
```

I want to do it in one statement instead of two. Is that possible?

Edit: I want an abbreviated way of doing it b/c right now this piece of code is in a loop that I want to put into a Linq statement. But when I convert it to Linq, I don't like the look of a three-line lambda to instantiate, set value, and return. So I'm looking for an alternative. Purely aesthetic.

Comment: Why don't you want to use two statements?

Comment: Making it one statement will result in less readable code, imo.

Comment: Why don't you wrap the two statements into their own routine that accepts `someLongVal` and spits out a new SqlDataRecord? Not as cool as an extension, maybe, but if all you want is to reduce that call into one line for readability a routine could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use method chaining with an extension!?

```
public static class DataRecordExtension
{
    public static SqlDataRecord WithInt64(this SqlDataRecord record, int ordinal, long value)
    {
        record.SetInt64(ordinal, value);
        return record;
    }
}
```

... and then use it like so:

```
var record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("n", SqlDbType.BigInt)).WithInt64(0, someValue);
```

Or build a helper for your needs ....

```
public class DataRecordHelper
{
    public static SqlDataRecord CreateDataRecordInt64(int ordinal, long value, params SqlMetaData[] metaData)
    {
        var record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
        record.SetInt64(ordinal, value);
        return record;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're just going to create a method why not just use something sensibly designed and write a method that creates and configures a `SqlDataRecord` and be done with it?

Comment: @Steve Why?  It seems reasonable to ask the author of the answer why they'd use a really confusing and misleading design for an answer rather than a more sensible one that would also meet the question's requirements.

Comment: To me, it's neither confusing nor misleading. This is a fine answer for me, at least. If there's no native way of doing it (i.e. without using extensions), I'll mark this as the answer by tomorrow.

Comment: @Servy i don´t think my answer confuses.  method chaining keeps code clean and readable. but that is just my oppinion :)

Comment: @Trevor Generally a method is either going to compute a value, or perform an operation.  The method returning a value implies that it's creating a new SqlDataRecord, not just mutating the provided one, as would be implied by it being a `void` method.

Comment: @MartinE When you have immutable objects, sure.  When they're just mutating the objects it's emulating immutable design without actually being immutable.  It has none of the benefits and all of the drawbacks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a single operation that performs multiple operations, you create a method that does those multiple operations.  So if you want an operation that creates an initialized `SqlDataRecord`, then write a method that creates an initialized `SqlDataRecord`.

```
public static SqlDataRecord CreateDataRecord(long value)
{
    var record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("n", SqlDbType.BigInt));
    record.SetInt64(0, value);
    return record;
}
```